# HQL - Query join table directly

Tags: grails, many-to-many, hql

I'm looking to write an HQL query to check if a particular pair exists in a join table for a many-to-many relation in Grails.

The SQL is easy:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM [ProjectCalculator].[dbo].[task_project]
WHERE task_id=[task_id] AND project_id=[project_id]
```

**Code:**

```
class Project {

String title
...

static belongsTo = [Task, Modifier]
static hasMany = [tasks:Task, modifiers : Modifier]
...
}

class Task {

    String description

    static hasMany = [project:Project]

...
}
```

I can't figure out how to write the HQL for this so it's database agnostic.

The reason for this question is when I add an existing task to a project I receive no error:

ex:
projectInstance.addToTasks(task).save(flush : true)

If the task already exists for the project I would have expected to get a duplicate primary key error from the database but I don't receive any notification regarding this. It simply fails silently.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can pass param "failOnError:true " which throws ValidationException. Don't know if it catches SQLException. Haven't tried it. 
Also you can set logSql = true in your DataSource.groovy to print query in console.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be quering the join table, that is SQL-way no the Hibernate-way. 
The problem you may be facing is related in how many-to-many relationships work in hibernate/grom.

Add static `mappedBy = [project: "none"]`to the `Task` class (and generate/run the migration if you are using a persistent database), that should fix your problem and you should be able of do

> projectInstance.addToTasks(task).save(flush : true)

I can't remember now if `mappedBy = [tasks: "none"]` in the `Proyect` class is also needed in this case.